# Recursive 'type' declaration in VHDL

Tags: recursion, vhdl

I wonder if this or something similar is possible:

```
package my_package is
  constant my_constant:integer:=4;
  type array_type1 is array(my_constant-1 downto 0)of integer;
  constant constant_array1:array_type1:=(62,47,28,76);
  --And here is the experimental part:
  for i in 0 to my_constnat-1 loop
    type array_type2 is array(my_constant-1 downto 0)of string(1 to constant_array1(i));
  end loop;
  constant constant_array2:array_type2:=(
    "Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.",--62 characters.
    "Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.",
    "So it's range is '1 to 47'.",
    "And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'."
  );
end my_package;
```

My final purpose is to create an array of strings while each string has a different length. Hopefully, this array will be used in a different file in the project with just declaring:

`use work.my_package.all;`

But I get the following error:

`Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at txt-utilities.vhd(16) near text "for";  expecting "end", or a declaration statement`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a generic array whose elements have increasing width in VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960367/creating-a-generic-array-whose-elements-have-increasing-width-in-vhdl)

Comment: This will not work, because for-loops are not allowed in packages. Secondly, each iterarion overrides `array_type2`.

Comment: To advice an alternative solution, can you tell the intended use for this, e.g. is it for simulation or synthesis, and how is the `constant_array2` used?

Comment: Hopefully I would like to use it for synthesis. It's supposed to be a module that presents these sentences on a LCD display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From IEEE Std 1076-2008:

> **5.3.2 Array types**
>   **5.3.2.1 General**
>
> An array object is a composite object consisting of elements that have the same subtype.

Subtype provides a constraint. In the context of an array type that is an array constraint (See **6.3 Subtype declarations** and **5.3.2 Array types**) which is a range.

So the  array as an element of an array has to have the same range of any other element and your method can't work (as Paebbels points out).

**There is at least one alternative method to index strings**

A function can return any value of any subtype of it's return type if the type mark is a base type.

This can be demonstrated by:

```
package my_package is
    constant my_constant:   integer := 4;
    function my_string (index: natural) return string;
end package;

package body  my_package is
    function my_string (index: natural) return string is
        begin
            assert index < my_constant 
                report "my_string(" & integer'image(index) &") provides a range of elements greater than my_constant"
                severity ERROR;
            case index is
                when 0 =>
                    return "Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.";
                when 1 =>
                    return "Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.";
                when 2 => 
                    return  "So it's range is '1 to 47'.";
                when 3 => 
                    return "And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.";
                when others => 
                    return "<ERROR>";
            end case;
        end function;
end package body;

use work.my_package.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    constant my_string0: string (my_string(0)'range) := my_string(0);
begin 
    process
    begin
        report my_string0;
        report "my_string0'length = " &integer'image(my_string0'length);
        for i in 1 to my_constant loop  -- this will provide a call out of range
            report my_string(i);
            report "my_string(" &integer'image(i) &") length = " &integer'image(my_string(i)'length);
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The package and demonstrating VHDL code analyzes, elaborates and when run produces:

> ghdl -r foo
>   my_package.vhdl:37:9:@0ms:(report note): Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.
>   my_package.vhdl:38:9:@0ms:(report note): my_string0'length = 61
>   my_package.vhdl:40:13:@0ms:(report note): Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.
>   my_package.vhdl:41:13:@0ms:(report note): my_string(1) length = 46
>   my_package.vhdl:40:13:@0ms:(report note): So it's range is '1 to 47'.
>   my_package.vhdl:41:13:@0ms:(report note): my_string(2) length = 27
>   my_package.vhdl:40:13:@0ms:(report note): And the range of this sentence is: '1 to '.
>   my_package.vhdl:41:13:@0ms:(report note): my_string(3) length = 75
>   my_package.vhdl:9:13:@0ms:(assertion error): my_string(4) provides a
>   range of elements greater than my_constant
>   my_package.vhdl:40:13:@0ms:(report note): <ERROR>
>   my_package.vhdl:9:13:@0ms:(assertion error): my_string(4) provides a range of elements greater than my_constant
>   my_package.vhdl:41:13:@0ms:(report note): my_string(4) length = 7

The constant declaration for `my_string0` shows how to use the function call in an object declaration.

You could note your expectations of string length don't appear to match VHDL, you consistently stated they were longer by 1. VHDL has no in band end of string signalling.

Hazarding a guess, you're after away of centrally defining some strings you can index for particular uses. A function as above would do that.

**Using an array of constant length strings**

If you were to set up an array of strings with the maximum length  of the longest constant string you could use a function to pare down the return string to length:

```
package my_package is
    constant my_constant:   natural := 4;
    constant LONGEST_STRING: natural := 75;

    function my_string (index: natural) return string;
end package;

package body my_package is
    type array_type1 is array(0 to my_constant - 1) of integer;

    constant constant_array1: array_type1 := (62, 47, 28, 76);

    type array_type2 is array (natural range 0 to my_constant - 1) of string (1 to LONGEST_STRING);

    constant constant_array: array_type2 := (
        0 => ("Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project."
               & string'(constant_array1(0) to LONGEST_STRING => ' ')),
        1 => ("Another sentence, with 47 characters at total."
               & string'(constant_array1(1) to LONGEST_STRING => ' ')),
        2 => ("So it's range is '1 to 47'." 
            & string'(constant_array1(2) to LONGEST_STRING => ' ')),
        3 => ("And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.")
    );

    function my_string (index: natural) return string is
    begin
        assert index < my_constant 
            report "my_string(" & integer'image(index) &") provides a range of elements greater than my_constant"
            severity ERROR;
        if index >= my_constant then
            return "<ERROR>";
        else
            return constant_array(index)(1 to constant_array1(index) - 1);
        end if;
    end function;
end package body;

use work.my_package.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    constant my_string0: string (my_string(0)'range) := my_string(0);
begin 
    process
    begin
        report my_string0;
        report "my_string0'length = " &integer'image(my_string0'length);
        for i in 1 to my_constant loop  -- this will provide a call out of range
            report my_string(i);
            report "my_string(" &integer'image(i) &") length = " &integer'image(my_string(i)'length);
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

When run this produces essentially the same output as the first example albeit with different line numbers and character pointers in the STANDARD OUTPUT from various report statements.

Comment: Thanks user1155120, I've a question: Generally in VHDL, is it possible to create a package with a type declaration of array, that it's range will be determined automatically according to the amount of values putted in it? Just like in C+ and other serial languages..

Comment: An unbound array type definition can have the index constraint provided at the time of a declaration of an object of that type (See 5.3.2.1).  From package standard,`type STRING is array (POSITIVE range <>) of CHARACTER;`. In declaring such an object you can provide the subtype indication from the supplied value - `constant c1: STRING := B"1111_1111_1111";` The expression on the RHS is a value of the type and provides an index constraint (1 to 12) where 1 is the leftmost value in a POSITIVE, (underscore's are not part of a bit string value).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to store all strings in one "super string" and separate them with some magic character or string (| in the example below). You can then use the [string_ops package](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/string_ops/src/string_ops.vhd) from [VUnit](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit) (I'm one of the authors) to split that long string into its components.

Another option is to use the frozen dictionary type [here](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/dictionary/src/dictionary.vhd) which is a string with key/value pairs

```
"key1 : value1, key2 : value2"
```

This allow you to get your strings by a key rather than using an index. Below is a VUnit testbench showing/verifying this. If you want more information on these packages you can look at their testbenches [here](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/string_ops/test/tb_string_ops.vhd) and [here](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/dictionary/test/tb_dictionary.vhd).

```
library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

package my_package is
  constant my_strings : string := "Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.|" &
                                  "Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.|" &
                                  "So it's range is '1 to 47'.|" &
                                  "And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.";

  constant my_dictionary : frozen_dictionary_t := "who am I : Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.," &
                                                  "foo : Another sentence,, with 47 characters at total.," &
                                                  "bar : So it's range is '1 to 47'.," &
                                                  "spam : And the range of this sentence is:: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.";
end package my_package;

library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

use work.my_package.all;

entity tb_test is
  generic (
    runner_cfg : runner_cfg_t);
end tb_test;

architecture tb of tb_test is

begin
  test_runner : process
    variable string_list : lines_t;
  begin
    test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);

    while test_suite loop
      if run("Test that variable length strings can be stored in a super string") then
        string_list := split(my_strings, "|");
        assert string_list(0).all = "Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.";
        assert string_list(1).all = "Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.";
        assert string_list(2).all = "So it's range is '1 to 47'.";
        assert string_list(3).all = "And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.";
      elsif run("Test that variable length strings can be stored in a dictionary") then
        assert get(my_dictionary, "who am I") = "Hello my name is Doron and I'm the developer of this project.";
        assert get(my_dictionary, "foo") = "Another sentence, with 47 characters at total.";
        assert get(my_dictionary, "bar") = "So it's range is '1 to 47'.";
        assert get(my_dictionary, "spam") = "And the range of this sentence is: '1 to <last-number-in-constant_array1>'.";
      end if;
    end loop;

    test_runner_cleanup(runner);
    wait;
  end process test_runner;
end;
```

.

```
d:\examples\array_of_variable_strings>python run.py
Starting lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a super string
pass (P=1 S=0 F=0 T=2) lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a super string (1.0 seconds)

Starting lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a dictionary
pass (P=2 S=0 F=0 T=2) lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a dictionary (0.9 seconds)

==== Summary =========================================================================================
pass lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a super string (1.0 seconds)
pass lib.tb_test.Test that variable length strings can be stored in a dictionary   (0.9 seconds)
======================================================================================================
pass 2 of 2
======================================================================================================
Total time was 1.9 seconds
Elapsed time was 1.9 seconds
======================================================================================================
All passed!

d:\examples\array_of_variable_strings>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there is not a simple solution that allows creation of an array of ragged arrays (having 2nd dimension of varying size).

OTOH, there are numerous creative solutions.  What I do in OSVVM to do this is to use an array of pointers to strings.  The following is a simplified version of MessagePkg that is part of OSVVM.  For the complete example, which has more capability than the code below, see http://osvvm.org

```
package MessagePkg is
  type MessagePType is protected
    procedure Set (MessageIn : String) ;
    impure function Get (ItemNumber : integer) return string ; 
    impure function GetCount return integer ; 
  end protected MessagePType ;
end package MessagePkg ;

package body MessagePkg is
  type MessagePType is protected body
    variable MessageCount : integer := 0 ; 
    constant MAX_MESSAGES : integer := 16 ; 
    -- type line is access string ; -- from std.textio
    type LineArrayType is array (natural 1 to MAX_MESSAGES) of line ; 
    variable MessageVar : LineArrayType ; 

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    procedure Set (MessageIn : String) is
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    begin
      MessageCount := MessageCount + 1 ; 
      assert MessageCount <= MAX_MESSAGES report "too many messages" severity FAILURE ; 
      MessageVar(MessageCount) := new string'(MessageIn) ;
    end procedure Set ; 

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    impure function Get (ItemNumber : integer) return string is
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    begin
      assert ItemNumber > 0 and ItemNumber <= MessageCount report "Get Index out of range" severity FAILURE ; 
      return MessageVar(ItemNumber).all ; 
    end function Get ; 

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    impure function GetCount return integer is 
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    begin
      return MessageCount ; 
    end function GetCount ; 
  end protected body MessagePType ;
end package body MessagePkg ;
```

To use MessagePType, you create a shared variable:

```
shared variable Message : MessagePType ; 
. . .
Message.Set("MessagePkg is part of OSVVM.");
Message.Set("OSVVM is a library of packages that provide next generation");
Message.Set("verification capabilty");
Message.Set("While the library implements constrained random and functional coverage, just like other languages");
Message.Set("It also implements a portable intelligent testbench capability that works in different simulators - something that Accellera is still working on");
```

To print the message, you can do the following:

```
 for i in 1 to Message.GetCount loop 
   write(OUTPUT, message.get(i) & LF) ;
 end loop ;
```

In OSVVM, the constant MAX_MESSAGES is replaced by a variable and when it is exceeded, the internal storage will automatically resize.  In OSVVM, MessagePkg.vhd is used by CoveragePkg.vhd.